# Python code in Ubuntu cannot find module mayavi mlab

Tags: python, ubuntu, package, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have installed the mayavi module using

```
sudo apt-get install mayavi2
```

and when I look within the python directory, I can see the mlab.py is here

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/mlab.py
```

But when run, the error is given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contour.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mayavi import mlab
  File "/home/USER/mayavi.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name mlab
```

From what I can tell, the python code is looking in the wrong place for the installed module. I've tried to sort this out, but I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

looks like module didn't installed correctly,

what do you see under

```
ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi
```

I have installed the same package and able to import it successfully, here is python interpreter ,

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mayavi import mlab
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'mlab']
>>>
```

Comment: I see both `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3018 Jan 20  2014 mlab.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4204 Jan 31 14:45 mlab.pyc` ? Typing the command from the interpreter has the same error as before.

Comment: Is there a file named `mayavi.py` in your working directory? If so, it will take precedence in `import` statements.

Comment: please re-install the package ... it should create a directory structure with few files & dirs